# SharePoint List Custom Form in Power Apps - Incorrect Sizing

Tags: list, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I am creating a custom form in Power Apps for one of my SharePoint List Entry Forms and am running into sizing issues that I can't find a solution for anywhere online.

My Form Screen is set up to use the App Height and Width and my App is Large Size in Settings.
On my monitor, the form is correct width, but shorter than the containing window's height.
On my laptop screen, the form height is larger than the containing window, so adds a secondary scrollbar that messes up the form width (adds another horizontal scrollbar).

[image: Monitor Form]
[image: Standard Screen Form]

I also tried to change the form screen dimensions (instead of inheriting from 'App') by increasing the height and resulted in the following Monitor Screen, with the width reduced and scaled for some reason.

[image: Monitor Form Changed Screen Dimensions]

I beleive all these issues could be fixed if the height of the form could update with the screen.
Surely there is a way that the form can resize it's height (and width) based on the containing window? Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me insane as well and could not find an answer anywhere as everyone kept saying to go to settings then display and that does not fix anything.  I did get it to work, follow the below. Quick note, when you make the last variable change in the Height, the preview will show everything go away, so make note to change this back to make any edits. But it works.

1. Open your form in PowerApps.
2. Select the SharePointIntegration control.
3. In the properties pane on the right, find the 'Advanced' section and click on 'More options' (the three dots).
4. Click on 'Unlock to change properties'.
5. Now, in the formula bar, find the 'OnNew' property and add this line of code: `NewForm(SharePointForm1); Set(varFormHeight, SharePointForm1.Height)`
6. Do the same for the 'OnEdit' and 'OnView' properties.
7. Now, select the form control (SharePointForm1 in this case).
8. In the properties pane, find the 'Height' property and set it to `varFormHeight`.
9. Save and publish your app.

This workaround uses a variable to dynamically set the height of the form based on the height of the SharePointIntegration control, which should fill the new form window.

Replace 'SharePointForm1' with the actual name of your form control if it's different.